# Unity greeter login screen has a garbled white dot grid?

Tags: unity, login, intel, unity-greeter

I am running 12.04 on three machines.  On one of the machines I am running an Intel 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller as a display adapter.  On this particular machine the grid of white dots overlaid on top of the wallpaper for the currently selected user is messed up big time.

Once I move the mouse, the graphics magically fix themselves.  Then if I select a new user the grid of dots is messed up again until I move the mouse.

Once I log in the graphics seem to be running fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be a bug, which you should report on launchpad.

Comment: Done - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/993366

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the white dots.

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false
```

Got it from [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/remove-white-dots-from-login-screen-of.html).