# Why does the lock screen adds a white dot grid over the background image?

Tags: 16.04, login-screen

I'm already aware of how to remove the dots from the login screen per these questions:

- [Unity greeter login screen has a garbled white dot grid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125839/unity-greeter-login-screen-has-a-garbled-white-dot-grid)
- [How do I remove the dots from the lockscreen in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452204/how-do-i-remove-the-dots-from-the-lockscreen-in-ubuntu-14-04)
- [How do I remove the dots from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72620/how-do-i-remove-the-dots-from-the-login-screen)

My question is: Why does Ubuntu do this? Is there a security reason or something else that explains why those dots are added to the login screen?

Comment: I also have this question regarding the lock screen. I first noticed it after changing the desktop wallpaper to a solid black color (to try to minimize distraction while working and save energy).